# Emacs. How to add a whitespace between all characters in a .txt file

Tags: emacs, whitespace

in Emacs I would like to know how to add a whitespace between every single character in a .txt file (very big file). Any suggestion is welcome. Thank you very much in advance

Input example:

```
122212121212121
212121212121212
121212121212121
```

Expected output:

```
1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the start of the file (`M-<`), then:

```
M-x replace-regexp

\(.\)

\1_
```

where `_` in the replacement string is a in fact space.

If you mind the trailing spaces you can remove them by going back to the start of the file and performing another substitution:

```
M-x replace-regexp

_$

(nothing)
```

where `_` is still a space made visible for convenience, `(nothing)` is, well, nothing. Just press Enter.

Comment: Thanks very much @cadrian. I get this:
1_2_2_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_
2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_
1_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_2_1_

I need to use this file in another software. I hope that software recognises the _ as a white space

Comment: Don't count on that. Where I wrote a `_` I just meant you to input a space! I just needed it to be quite visible ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just run <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(replace-string "" " ")`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and the start of the buffer.

You might need to delete the spaces at the beginnings and ends of lines.

Comment: Thanks very much @choroba, I tried in your way but for some reason it did not work well in my hands